# how to read a json web response representing a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, rest

I have a `json` response from a `FastAPI` `REST` `service` that is generated like this:

```
dfjson = df.to_json(orient='records', date_format='iso', indent=4)
```

and looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "Date":"2017-12-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        "RR":0.0,
        "Symbol":"AAPL"
    },
    {
        "Date":"2018-03-12T00:00:00.000Z",
        "RR":-0.0655954215,
        "Symbol":"AAPL"
    },
    {
        "Date":"2018-03-14T00:00:00.000Z",
        "RR":-0.0493162968,
        "Symbol":"AAPL"
    },
    {
        "Date":"2018-03-15T00:00:00.000Z",
        "RR":-0.0539632781,
        "Symbol":"AAPL"
    },
    ...
```

On the `client` side, I am trying to convert this `json` into a `pandas` `dataframe` thus:

```
df = pd.read_json(response.text)
print(df)
```

But I get an error:

```
....
raise ValueError("If using all scalar values, you must pass an index")
ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using `requests` or something similar to fetch the data? In that case, you probably want `response.json()`

Comment: What is the output of `print(response.text)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspected this was due to json strict format. And this is the case.

Please see my question [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75705845/difference-between-and-in-read-json?noredirect=1#comment133555611_75705845)

```py
pd.read_json(str(response).replace("'", '"'), orient='records')
```

```
                       Date        RR Symbol
0 2017-12-01 00:00:00+00:00  0.000000   AAPL
1 2018-03-12 00:00:00+00:00 -0.065595   AAPL
2 2018-03-14 00:00:00+00:00 -0.049316   AAPL
3 2018-03-15 00:00:00+00:00 -0.053963   AAPL
```